# Graphical issues with maximize/close buttons on Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

One of my friends encountered graphical issues with maximize/close buttons while using Google Chrome on his machine but I could not direct him how to solve the problem. Does anyone know why is this happening? Is it one of the Windows 7 updates?

Update:

The result of `sfc /scannow`:

> Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Restarting Chrome does solve the problem but only for some time.

It does seem like clearing the thumbnails cache in Windows helped.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Chrome?

Comment: This happens to the latest stable version and I was told not only in Chrome. I will try the suggested solutions and keep you guys posted.

Comment: Try to change theme because some time themes doesn't support as in my case few days ago `Firfox` was making me the problem. And may be for all windows that appearing in explorer.

Comment: @Darius: As noted in other comments, [update your question](http://superuser.com/posts/325498/edit) with more useful information rather than hiding those details away in the comments. This makes it easier for people that want to answer so they don't lose track on important details... :)

Comment: I agree with @Tom. Darius update your question for people to try to help you.

Comment: Also please note if any extensions or other add-ons are installed. Or any programs that add buttons to all windows or browsers. Though the affect is different, I have a somewhat-similar button issue from using [Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com).

Comment: @Tom Wijsman could you post an answer with the options you gave in your comment so you can get the appropriate recognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things one could look through:

- Does this only happen in Google Chrome?
- If so, what Google Chrome version are you running?
- Have you tried reinstalling Google Chrome to the latest stable non-developer version?
- Does this also happen in the non-maximized state?
- When did this started happening?
- Where there updates near this moment?
- What happens if you hover the buttons?
- Have you tried a System Restore?
- Have you tried `sfc /scannow` to see whether it repairs something?
- Did you try disk cleanup to [clear the thumbnail cache](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/clear-delete-the-thumbnail-cache-in-windows-7/)?
- What is the blue fill there?

Answer (score 2):

To troubleshoot the blurry buttons, and it's not just Chrome, try different resolutions and perhaps safe mode to see how it reacts. Perhaps try updating the video drivers.

Comment: There is a "Show in Status Bar" option you can use to remove the icon.

Comment: Take a look again, there's something odd about the buttons, not Ad Block Plus... :)

Comment: @Tom Wijsman - Exactly what I was heading at....

Comment: That appears to be Google Chrome... no, wait Microsoft Windows!

Comment: @Tom Wijsman Ohhhhhh... I thought he was asking about the icon, and the button weirdness was just a bad screen shot. :)

Comment: @Darius Perhaps update your question to clarify what in the picture you're asking about? :)

Comment: I did update the question :)

Comment: @techie007: I've edited out the irrelevant Adblock Plus content from your answer.